# Android SeekBar image resizing doesn't work

Tags: android, seekbar

I have used `SeekBar` in my android project to resize image but it doesn't work as my expectation I mean it is hiding the image instead of resizing.  Here is my code below:

```
seekbarSize.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
        tmp = (ImageView) findViewById(lastIdImage);
        tmp.requestLayout();
        tmp.getLayoutParams().height = ((500 * progresValue) / 100) + 30;
        tmp.getLayoutParams().width = ((500 * progresValue) / 100) + 30;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
});
```

Can anybody help me what I have done wrong inside the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final int WIDTH_SCALE_RATIO = 10;
private static final int HEIGHT_SCALE_RATIO = 10;
private int previousProcess = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView imgg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1))
            .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                    int diff = progresValue - previousProcess;
                    scaleImage(imgg, diff);
                    previousProcess = progresValue;
                }
            });
}

public void scaleImage(ImageView img, int scale) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    float width = bitmap.getWidth();
    float height = bitmap.getHeight();
    width += scale * WIDTH_SCALE_RATIO;
    height += scale * HEIGHT_SCALE_RATIO;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) width, (int) height,
            true);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: it may help you :)

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you are doing here?

Comment: @DharaChandarana scaleImage method scaling my entire layout instead of the image view.